# Simplify the logic to compare the two datasets

Tags: java, string, arraylist

**Problem Statement:-**

1. Firstly, I need to check whether all the `columns` that I have in `columnsList` is present in `attributes` `(attr.getName())` or not.
2. Secondly, If any `column` from `columnsList` is not present in `attributes` then `boolean foundData` should be false.
3. Thirdly, if any attribute status is not success then `boolean foundData` should be false.
4. Fourthly, If the `column` is present in attribute `(attr.getName())` and its status is success also, then increment the counter by one

`attr.getName()` will return the column name.

Below is the code I have. I am sure, I have messed up something in my below code.

```
List<String> columnsList = getColumns(service.getColumns());

List<Attribute<?>> attributes = beClient.getAttributes(columnsList);

for (String column : columnsList) {
    for(Attribute<?> attr : attributes) {
        if(!attr.getName().equals(column) || !attr.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {
            foundData=false;
            break;
        }  else if(attr.getName().equals(column) && attr.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                count_success.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

What wrong happening in my code is for each column it will check with attribute if it is not matching, it is going to if loop everytime. I believe which is not right.

Comment: Do you have any opposition to transforming the data?  That is, do you only want to work with `String` and `Attribute`, or are you willing to promote one?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong in the current code you posted?

Comment: @Makoto, Sorry I was not able to understand your comment. Pardon my ignorance. `getName` will always return string.

Comment: What I mean is, are you fine only extracting the `String` portion you're concerned about and running a comparison on that instead?

Comment: @Makoto, Yes. I am fine with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this re factored code will work...

```
List<String> columnsList = getColumns(service.getColumns());

List<Attribute<?>> attributes = beClient.getAttributes(columnsList);

for (String column : columnsList) {
    boolean isPresent =false;
    boolean isSuccess = true;

    for(Attribute<?> attr : attributes) {
        if(attr.getName().equals(column)){
            isPresent = true; 
        }       
        if(!attr.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")){
            isSuccess = false; 
        }
    }

    if(!isPresent || !isSuccess){
        foundData=false; 
    }else{
        count_success.incrementAndGet();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `Map<String,String>` for the attributes.  Then you can use the Collection utilities.  For example for step 1

```
ArrayList<String> copyOfColumns = new ArrayList<String>(columnsList );
copyOfColumns.removeAll(map.keySet());
if (copyOfColumns.size() > 0)
  // you have a column that isn't in the attribute
```

For step 3 its trivial, something like:

```
if (map.values().contains("FAILURE"))
  // you had a failure
```

I'll leave the others as exercises...  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. What is this Map holding?

Comment: The "key" is the AttributeName, the value is the attribute Status (from getName() and getStatus() in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Implement equals and hashcode for the attribute name. Iterate the columnList and create an Attribute object. Then check if that attribute is present in the Attribute list. Then your code will be simple.